# App Handlers - change order of multiple addons?

Tags: python, scripting

Its clear that "bpy.app.handlers.render_pre" gets called before "bpy.app.handlers.render_post".

But what happens if I have two or more addons which all add to the "bpy.app.handlers.render_pre"? How do I know in which order they are getting called and is there a way to change that order by myself?